# How to start activity after user "login" into Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to write an app (activity, toast, service, whatever) that starts automatically after the user has "logged in" into the system (i.e. after the user rotates the Android wheel). I don't see any broadcast intent for that.

Is that possible somehow?

PS: This would be for Android 3.0 and above

Comment: I'm confused a little by your question, do you mean you want it to start each time the user unlocks the screen?

Answer (score 0):

This event is broadcasted as [android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT).